# Angular: Prevent additional whitespaces in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a html template which should simply translate a state:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="currentStatus">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'DRAFT'" i18n="@@DraftStatus">
    Draft
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase=    ...
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    {{currentStatus}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
. End
```

But somehow as much as I try the content is always displayed as e.g. `Draft . End`. i.e. one additional space is added at the end of the container. I would 
like to display it like `Draft. End`.

Trying to use in the `compontent` the setting `preserveWhitespaces: false,` doesn't help neither.

Any hints how to get rid of this extra space?

Comment: Maybe that you have an additionnal space after Draft or End. Try inlining the tag:
`<ng-container *ngSwitchDefault> {{currentStatus}}</ng-container>` and see if you still have the trailing space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have necessarily a white space that you do not see. To be sure you can wrap your words in `<span>` like :

```html
...
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'DRAFT'" i18n="@@DraftStatus">
   <span>Draft</span>
</ng-container>
...
<span>. End</span>
```

And be sure that you do not have space between your tags

Comment: Yeah, that's the best approach to fix this issue on a long run. I don't want to rely on any special formatting within HTML - cuz my editor might mess it up. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You might not like this formatting (or perhaps you have auto-format on save set up, which would have to be disabled somehow), but this should solve the problem:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="currentStatus">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'DRAFT'" i18n="@@DraftStatus">
    Draft</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase=    ...
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    {{currentStatus}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>. End
```